# ResourceManager.GetString returns "" when the value is " " in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

ResourceManager.GetString returns " " in .NET Freamework, but the exact same method returns "" in .NETCore. The actual value is " "

Here is a simple .NET Core program:

```
    namespace ResxTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            var resourceManager = new ResourceManager("ResxTest.Resource1", typeof(Program).Assembly);

            var test1 = resourceManager.GetString("all_space");
            var test2 = resourceManager.GetString("begin_with_space");
            var test3 = resourceManager.GetString("end_with_space");
            var test4 = resourceManager.GetString("no_space");
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
}
```

if you run it, test1 will be "" instead of " "

Resource1.resx (added the resx file as a new item in Visual Studio => did not make it manually):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>

  <xsd:schema id="root" xmlns="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" />
    <xsd:element name="root" msdata:IsDataSet="true">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:element name="metadata">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="assembly">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:attribute name="alias" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="data">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
                <xsd:element name="comment" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="3" />
              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="4" />
              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="resheader">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:choice>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:schema>
  <resheader name="resmimetype">
    <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="version">
    <value>2.0</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="reader">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="writer">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <data name="all_space" xml:space="preserve">
    <value> </value>
  </data>
  <data name="begin_with_space" xml:space="preserve">
    <value> x</value>
  </data>
  <data name="end_with_space" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>x </value>
  </data>
  <data name="no_space" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>x</value>
  </data>
</root>
```

Comment: Have you double checked this? What if you put a value in it? Also what culture is this? and is this actually a space apposed to a character that looks like a space? You need to put more effort, proof and debugging into this question

Comment: Please provide [MCVE] - that is unlikely to happen if indeed code is the way you describe.

Comment: @MichaelRandall it works fine when a put a value in it (something other than space), but it returns "" even if I enter 20 consecutive spaces without any other characters. and yes, I made sure that's actually space (the exact same resx and code work just fine in .NET Framework, but not in .NET Core).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov added to the post